# Caching Filtered Data After Filtering Unwanted Data

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

Imagine I have a data type called:
`Result`
Which contains more data types. Take this data for an example:

```
[{Albums : { 
  name: “albumName”,
  artist: {name: “artistName,
           link:“https:link.com”
           },
  link: “http...”
       }   Tracks: {
  name: “trackName”,
  artist: {name: “artistName,
           link:“https:link.com”
           },
  link: “http...”
       }    Playlists: {
  name: “playlistName”,
  artist: {name: “artistName,
           link:“https:link.com”
           },
  link: “http...”
       }
}]
```

Imagine you have filtered the data using any kind of method and the value you only want to get is the names, so you do the filter thing and then cache all the values that is filtered so that when you call the api again, there is no need for filtering it again since you can get it straight in the cache. Is this even possible with or without `@Cachaeble` and is there any improvement in the performance?

Comment: Do you call the API with different parameters and get different results? Is the filter criteria a parameter as well,, this dynamic, or static? When do you expect the cached value to expire, or, in other words, when should the cached data be updated?

Comment: Yes I do call the API with different parameters and get different results but sometimes, results that are returned may already be in an API call before. The filter criteria is static i.e. filtering by getting only the names. For the last question, I don't think I need to answer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is quite generic at the moment, so I do a generic answer:

It is possible with `Cacheable` or without, which means you call a cache implementation directly or implement the caching mechanism by yourself. The performance increase depends on the latency of your API calls, the latency / CPU consumption for the filter in contrast to the processing overhead of caching, which is the Spring cache abstraction and the cache solution.

If there is only a few different queries requested repeatedly your cache will be effective. If you have lots of different queries and not much repetition your cache might be uneffective and/or consume a lot of memory.

Comment: Is there any downsides of just implementing the Cache interface of spring and then do a foreach and over ride the get method from Cache interface to cache the values I want and not the Cacheable annotation? I don't see any simple solutions of doing the @Cacheable annotation since I would need keys for the individual values compared to implementing my own caching mechanism using the get methods from cache.

Comment: I'd like to personally ask you if a bunch of for each from java streams for getting and putting in the cache is arguably better than using spring's cache abstraction given the fact that some values of an API call might already have the filtered value from the cache which reduces the amount of filtering.

Comment: I cannot fully understand what you are asking or comparing. May it makes sense to put this in another question and have some code examples to refer to.

Comment: Please mind that "better" can have different meanings depending in which direction you want to optimize. Sometimes there is a "universal better" solution, but most of the time its an optimization towards some design goals.

Comment: Please take a look at this specific question that I have posted.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65034732/is-doing-my-own-cache-implementation-better-or-using-cacheable-in-spring-cache.